# How in SQL (MySQL) create request or by varible, or by all records?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any way to create `IF` statement in SQL depended of value to replace ANY_VALUE from this statement?
Example:

```
WHERE
date BETWEEN :start AND :end
AND IF (:id, id IN (:id), ANY_VALUE(idcolumn))
```

Is there a more productive or more "beautiful" way?

Comment: You need to filter by passed variable or if no variable provided then select all the data, right?

Comment: *IF (:id, id IN (:id), ANY_VALUE(idcolumn))* Does `:id` contains single value or a list of values (CSV, etc.)? If second then does `ANY_VALUE(idcolumn)` means "one any row from `:id` list"?

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, but if you need to get filtered data when variable is not null, and all data when variable is null, then simply use `:id IS NULL OR id IN (:id)`

Comment: @astentx, Correct

Comment: @Strawberry will do a little bit later, question is more "theoretical"

Comment: Nothing like a practical illustration to explicate a theoretical problem

Comment: @Akina, No, it means that if any value in :id must filter by this value or list, if no values - any value from idcolumn

Comment: `where ... and ( (:id is not null and id = :id) or :id is null)`

Comment: For list binding it is more complicated, you have to construct dynamic query with exploded list, as far as I know. So for this case you do not need any SQL tricks, you can pass `1 = 1` if your list variable is empty.

Comment: *No, it means that if any value in :id must filter by this value or list, if no values - any value from idcolumn* Again. `:id` may be empty (what it contains in this case? NULL? 'null'? empty string?) or contain only one value? Or it may contain a list of values? Any value means any one row with any value of all possible or all rows?